# How to declare range based grouping in pd.Dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am have this code which works fine but it only groups based on one number. i.e. 
`8=group A` 
`3=group B` 
`4=group C` 
`2=group D`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'nb_people':[8,3,4,2], 'group':["group A", "group B", "group C", "group D"] })
```

I am actually looking to group in the following manner:
`8-10=group C` 
`5-7=group B` 
`2-4=group A`

How can I incorporate ranges in this code? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe something with `pd.cut`

Comment: It is NOT a duplicate! The other posts are somewhat different. Can somebody please help?